# How can I use "connect()" in flask-socketio?

Tags: flask-socketio

I want to flask start server as usual and after a request, I want to make a socket connection.

Just like it's working here: [YouTube link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OZ1yQTbtf5E)

I tried starting server using `app.run()` instead of usual `socketio.run()` but It still was running socket connection!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting the server with socketio.run() does not start a socket connection. The server behaves like a normal Flask server until a client uses a Socket.IO client to request a Socket.IO connection.

If you have a server configured for Socket.IO and you start it with app.run you will be starting a partial server. Some things will work, some other won't. WebSocket will not work for sure. And depending on the version of Flask things may more or less work, or not work at all. The socketio.run function is a wrapper for app.run that starts the Flask server with the proper configuration to create Socket.IO connections.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Miguel.